# Install tensorflow 1.15 failed with pytorch in anaconda

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, conda

I am trying to install tensorflow-gpu with conda,  and my OS is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. But got this error:

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/linux-64::entrypoints==0.3=py37_0
  - defaults/noarch::seaborn==0.11.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::threadpoolctl==2.2.0=pyh0d69192_0
  - defaults/linux-64::greenlet==1.1.1=py37h295c915_0
  - defaults/noarch::ptyprocess==0.7.0=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - defaults/noarch::zipp==3.7.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pycosat==0.6.3=py37h27cfd23_0
  - defaults/noarch::pyflakes==2.3.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::get_terminal_size==1.0.0=haa9412d_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libxslt==1.1.34=hc22bd24_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libxcb==1.14=h7b6447c_0
  - defaults/linux-64::kiwisolver==1.3.1=py37h2531618_0
  - defaults/linux-64::tk==8.6.11=h1ccaba5_0
  - defaults/noarch::textdistance==4.2.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::fsspec==2022.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::zope==1.0=py37_1
  - defaults/noarch::cloudpickle==2.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::jdcal==1.4.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::imagecodecs==2021.8.26=py37h4cda21f_0
  - defaults/noarch::python-lsp-jsonrpc==1.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::chardet==4.0.0=py37h06a4308_1003
  - defaults/linux-64::multipledispatch==0.6.0=py37_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libuuid==1.0.3=h7f8727e_2
  - defaults/linux-64::zope.event==4.5.0=py37_0
  - defaults/linux-64::mkl_fft==1.3.1=py37hd3c417c_0
  - defaults/linux-64::matplotlib==3.5.0=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/linux-64::bottleneck==1.3.2=py37heb32a55_1
  - defaults/noarch::urllib3==1.26.7=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.2.4=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libev==4.33=h7f8727e_1
  - defaults/linux-64::ncurses==6.3=h7f8727e_2
  - defaults/noarch::whichcraft==0.6.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::yapf==0.31.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::sphinxcontrib==1.0=py37_1
  - defaults/noarch::tinycss==0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_1002
  - defaults/noarch::binaryornot==0.4.4=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/linux-64::mkl_random==1.2.2=py37h51133e4_0
  - defaults/noarch::nbclassic==0.2.6=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::python-slugify==5.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::testpath==0.5.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::ply==3.11=py37_0
  - defaults/noarch::flake8==3.9.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::anaconda==custom=py37_1
  - defaults/noarch::ipython_genutils==0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/linux-64::distributed==2021.10.0=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::json5==0.9.6=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pyodbc==4.0.32=py37h295c915_0
  - defaults/linux-64::cffi==1.14.6=py37h400218f_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libwebp-base==1.2.0=h27cfd23_0
  - defaults/linux-64::jupyter==1.0.0=py37_7
  - defaults/noarch::unidecode==1.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::mpich==3.3.2=hc856adb_0
  - defaults/noarch::pyxdg==0.27=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::fribidi==1.0.10=h7b6447c_0
  - defaults/linux-64::ninja==1.10.2=py37hd09550d_3
  - defaults/noarch::path.py==12.5.0=hd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::zlib==1.2.11=h7f8727e_4
  - defaults/noarch::fonttools==4.25.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::bkcharts==0.2=py37_0
  - defaults/linux-64::debugpy==1.5.1=py37h295c915_0
  - defaults/linux-64::gmpy2==2.0.8=py37h10f8cd9_2
  - defaults/linux-64::astroid==2.6.6=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::more-itertools==8.12.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pyrsistent==0.18.0=py37heee7806_0
  - defaults/linux-64::curl==7.80.0=h7f8727e_0
  - defaults/noarch::packaging==21.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::py-lief==0.10.1=py37h403a769_0
  - defaults/noarch::jeepney==0.7.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::mistune==0.8.4=py37h14c3975_1001
  - defaults/linux-64::libuv==1.40.0=h7b6447c_0
  - defaults/linux-64::spyder==5.1.5=py37h06a4308_1
  - defaults/linux-64::numpy==1.20.3=py37hf144106_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pathlib2==2.3.6=py37h06a4308_2
  - defaults/linux-64::jxrlib==1.1=h7b6447c_2
  - defaults/noarch::joblib==1.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::bleach==4.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::lxml==4.7.1=py37h1f438cf_1
  - defaults/linux-64::keyring==23.4.0=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/linux-64::clyent==1.2.2=py37_1
  - defaults/linux-64::pixman==0.40.0=h7f8727e_1
  - defaults/noarch::black==19.10b0=py_0
  - defaults/noarch::wcwidth==0.2.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::werkzeug==2.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::send2trash==1.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/linux-64::zope.interface==5.4.0=py37h7f8727e_0
  - defaults/noarch::iniconfig==1.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::munkres==1.1.4=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1
  - defaults/linux-64::statsmodels==0.12.2=py37h27cfd23_0
  - defaults/noarch::python-dateutil==2.8.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libcurl==7.80.0=h0b77cf5_0
  - defaults/noarch::jinja2-time==0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - defaults/linux-64::pyqt==5.9.2=py37h05f1152_2
  - defaults/linux-64::dal==2021.4.0=h06a4308_729
  - defaults/noarch::tifffile==2021.7.2=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - defaults/linux-64::jupyter_server==1.4.1=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/linux-64::notebook==6.4.6=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::toolz==0.11.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::sortedcollections==2.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::tbb4py==2021.5.0=py37hd09550d_0
  - defaults/linux-64::jbig==2.1=hdba287a_0
  - defaults/linux-64::mpmath==1.2.1=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::tblib==1.7.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::jinja2==2.11.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::jupyterlab_pygments==0.1.2=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::cytoolz==0.11.0=py37h7b6447c_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libaec==1.0.4=he6710b0_1
  - defaults/linux-64::zeromq==4.3.4=h2531618_0
  - defaults/noarch::backports.shutil_get_terminal_size==1.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_3
  - pytorch/linux-64::pytorch==1.7.1=py3.7_cuda10.1.243_cudnn7.6.3_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libssh2==1.9.0=h1ba5d50_1
  - defaults/linux-64::pycurl==7.44.1=py37h8f2d780_1
  - defaults/linux-64::unicodecsv==0.14.1=py37_0
  - defaults/linux-64::secretstorage==3.3.1=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::jsonschema==3.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - defaults/linux-64::libtiff==4.2.0=h85742a9_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libllvm11==11.1.0=h3826bc1_0
  - defaults/linux-64::cryptography==36.0.0=py37h9ce1e76_0
  - defaults/noarch::singledispatch==3.7.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1001
  - defaults/noarch::dask-core==2021.10.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::nltk==3.6.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::tqdm==4.62.3=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/noarch::pyopenssl==21.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/linux-64::argon2-cffi==20.1.0=py37h27cfd23_1
  - defaults/linux-64::arrow==0.13.1=py37_0
  - defaults/noarch::nbformat==5.1.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libdeflate==1.8=h7f8727e_5
  - defaults/linux-64::pkginfo==1.7.1=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/linux-64::locket==0.2.1=py37h06a4308_1
  - defaults/noarch::beautifulsoup4==4.10.0=pyh06a4308_0
  - defaults/linux-64::jupyter_core==4.9.1=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pcre==8.45=h295c915_0
  - defaults/linux-64::ipython==7.29.0=py37hb070fc8_0
  - defaults/noarch::heapdict==1.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::c-ares==1.18.1=h7f8727e_0
  - defaults/noarch::toml==0.10.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::importlib-metadata==4.8.2=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::asn1crypto==1.4.0=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::nbconvert==6.3.0=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::matplotlib-inline==0.1.2=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - defaults/linux-64::matplotlib-base==3.5.0=py37h3ed280b_0
  - defaults/noarch::qstylizer==0.1.10=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::zict==2.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libstdcxx-ng==9.3.0=hd4cf53a_17
  - defaults/linux-64::brunsli==0.1=h2531618_0
  - defaults/noarch::jupyterlab_widgets==1.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/linux-64::dbus==1.13.18=hb2f20db_0
  - defaults/noarch::qtconsole==5.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::giflib==5.2.1=h7b6447c_0
  - defaults/linux-64::ipykernel==6.4.1=py37h06a4308_1
  - defaults/noarch::py==1.10.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::diff-match-patch==20200713=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::hdf5==1.10.4=hb1b8bf9_0
  - defaults/linux-64::sqlite==3.37.0=hc218d9a_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pep8==1.7.1=py37_0
  - defaults/noarch::text-unidecode==1.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pillow==8.4.0=py37h5aabda8_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libedit==3.1.20210910=h7f8727e_0
  - pytorch/linux-64::torchaudio==0.7.2=py37
  - defaults/noarch::backcall==0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::filelock==3.4.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libnghttp2==1.46.0=hce63b2e_0
  - defaults/linux-64::conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py37h27cfd23_1
  - defaults/noarch::decorator==5.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==2.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::poyo==0.5.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::idna==3.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::three-merge==0.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::gmp==6.2.1=h2531618_2
  - defaults/linux-64::liblief==0.10.1=he6710b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::argcomplete==1.12.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libxml2==2.9.12=h03d6c58_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pysocks==1.7.1=py37_1
  - defaults/linux-64::pyerfa==2.0.0=py37h27cfd23_0
  - defaults/linux-64::icu==58.2=he6710b0_3
  - defaults/linux-64::bitarray==2.3.5=py37h7f8727e_0
  - defaults/linux-64::docutils==0.18.1=py37h06a4308_2
  - defaults/linux-64::conda==4.11.0=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/linux-64::freetype==2.11.0=h70c0345_0
  - defaults/linux-64::webencodings==0.5.1=py37_1
  - defaults/noarch::six==1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::qtawesome==1.0.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::scikit-learn-intelex==2021.4.0=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/linux-64::jpeg==9d=h7f8727e_0
  - defaults/linux-64::llvmlite==0.37.0=py37h295c915_1
  - defaults/linux-64::pytables==3.6.1=py37h71ec239_0
  - defaults/linux-64::gstreamer==1.14.0=h28cd5cc_2
  - defaults/linux-64::libtool==2.4.6=h7b6447c_1005
  - defaults/linux-64::psutil==5.8.0=py37h27cfd23_1
  - defaults/linux-64::certifi==2021.10.8=py37h06a4308_2
  - defaults/noarch::pycparser==2.21=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pywavelets==1.1.1=py37h7b6447c_2
  - defaults/noarch::typing-extensions==3.10.0.2=hd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::et_xmlfile==1.1.0=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/linux-64::wurlitzer==3.0.2=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::jupyter_console==6.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::bzip2==1.0.8=h7b6447c_0
  - defaults/noarch::pygments==2.10.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::isort==5.9.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::dask==2021.10.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::scikit-learn==1.0.2=py37h51133e4_1
  - defaults/noarch::attrs==21.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::soupsieve==2.3.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::ipywidgets==7.6.5=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/linux-64::astropy==4.3.1=py37h09021b7_0
  - defaults/linux-64::ujson==4.2.0=py37h295c915_0
  - defaults/linux-64::expat==2.4.1=h2531618_2
  - defaults/linux-64::brotli==1.0.9=he6710b0_2
  - defaults/noarch::prometheus_client==0.12.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::mypy_extensions==0.4.3=py37h06a4308_1
  - defaults/noarch::backports==1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pango==1.45.3=hd140c19_0
  - defaults/noarch::sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::cython==0.29.25=py37hdbfa776_0
  - defaults/noarch::numpydoc==1.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/linux-64::harfbuzz==2.8.1=h6f93f22_0
  - defaults/noarch::autopep8==1.6.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::krb5==1.19.2=hac12032_0
  - defaults/linux-64::sqlalchemy==1.4.27=py37h7f8727e_0
  - defaults/linux-64::lz4-c==1.9.3=h295c915_1
  - defaults/noarch::imageio==2.9.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::xz==5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - defaults/noarch::glob2==0.7=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::gst-plugins-base==1.14.0=h8213a91_2
  - defaults/noarch::imagesize==1.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::h5py==2.10.0=py37h7918eee_0
  - defaults/linux-64::async_generator==1.10=py37h28b3542_0
  - defaults/linux-64::markupsafe==1.1.1=py37h14c3975_1
  - defaults/linux-64::libspatialindex==1.9.3=h2531618_0
  - defaults/linux-64::ruamel_yaml==0.15.100=py37h27cfd23_0
  - defaults/linux-64::zfp==0.5.5=h295c915_6
  - defaults/noarch::pytz==2021.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::lzo==2.10=h7b6447c_2
  - defaults/linux-64::libsodium==1.0.18=h7b6447c_0
  - defaults/linux-64::scikit-image==0.18.3=py37h51133e4_0
  - defaults/linux-64::graphite2==1.3.14=h23475e2_0
  - defaults/linux-64::patsy==0.5.2=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::python-libarchive-c==2.9=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/noarch::anaconda-project==0.10.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::sniffio==1.2.0=py37h06a4308_1
  - defaults/linux-64::terminado==0.9.4=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::jupyterlab==3.2.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/linux-64::daal4py==2021.4.0=py37h78b71dc_0
  - defaults/linux-64::regex==2021.11.2=py37h7f8727e_0
  - defaults/noarch::partd==1.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::traitlets==5.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::python==3.7.11=h12debd9_0
  - defaults/linux-64::jedi==0.18.0=py37h06a4308_1
  - defaults/noarch::nbclient==0.5.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::cairo==1.16.0=hf32fb01_1
  - defaults/linux-64::tbb==2021.5.0=hd09550d_0
  - defaults/linux-64::gevent==21.8.0=py37h7f8727e_1
  - defaults/noarch::cycler==0.11.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::mkl-service==2.4.0=py37h7f8727e_0
  - defaults/noarch::defusedxml==0.7.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pyzmq==22.3.0=py37h295c915_2
  - defaults/noarch::typing_extensions==3.10.0.2=pyh06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::conda-content-trust==0.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::readline==8.1.2=h7f8727e_1
  - defaults/linux-64::sphinx==1.8.5=py37_0
  - defaults/noarch::qtpy==1.10.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pycrypto==2.6.1=py37h7b6447c_10
  - defaults/linux-64::libwebp==1.2.0=h89dd481_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libpng==1.6.37=hbc83047_0
  - defaults/linux-64::sip==4.19.8=py37hf484d3e_0
  - defaults/noarch::nose==1.3.7=pyhd3eb1b0_1006
  - defaults/linux-64::torchvision==0.8.2=cpu_py37ha229d99_0
  - defaults/noarch::flask==1.1.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::numba==0.54.1=py37h51133e4_0
  - defaults/linux-64::typed-ast==1.4.3=py37h7f8727e_1
  - defaults/linux-64::pluggy==1.0.0=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::prompt_toolkit==3.0.20=hd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::mpfr==4.0.2=hb69a4c5_1
  - defaults/noarch::pyls-spyder==0.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::conda-token==0.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::networkx==2.6.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::sympy==1.9=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::cookiecutter==1.7.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::jupyter_client==6.1.12=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::blosc==1.21.0=h8c45485_0
  - defaults/noarch::qdarkstyle==3.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::unixodbc==2.3.9=h7b6447c_0
  - defaults/noarch::nest-asyncio==1.5.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::openssl==1.1.1m=h7f8727e_0
  - defaults/noarch::colorama==0.4.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::numexpr==2.8.1=py37h6abb31d_0
  - defaults/linux-64::mpc==1.1.0=h10f8cd9_1
  - defaults/noarch::pycodestyle==2.7.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::html5lib==1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::rtree==0.9.7=py37h06a4308_1
  - defaults/linux-64::argh==0.26.2=py37_0
  - defaults/linux-64::alabaster==0.7.12=py37_0
  - defaults/noarch::sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::prompt-toolkit==3.0.20=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::atomicwrites==1.4.0=py_0
  - defaults/noarch::pathspec==0.7.0=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::xlwt==1.3.0=py37_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libgcc-ng==9.3.0=h5101ec6_17
  - defaults/noarch::contextlib2==0.6.0.post1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::tornado==6.1=py37h27cfd23_0
  - defaults/linux-64::msgpack-python==1.0.2=py37hff7bd54_1
  - defaults/linux-64::cfitsio==3.470=hf0d0db6_6
  - defaults/noarch::pydocstyle==6.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::snappy==1.1.8=he6710b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::zstd==1.4.9=haebb681_0
  - defaults/noarch::python-lsp-black==1.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::python-lsp-server==1.2.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libarchive==3.4.2=h62408e4_0
  - defaults/linux-64::glib==2.69.1=h5202010_0
  - defaults/linux-64::bokeh==2.4.2=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::jupyterlab_server==2.10.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/noarch::babel==2.9.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::openjpeg==2.4.0=h3ad879b_0
  - defaults/linux-64::anyio==2.2.0=py37h06a4308_1
  - defaults/linux-64::yaml==0.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libzopfli==1.0.3=he6710b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::pexpect==4.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_3
  - defaults/noarch::requests==2.27.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::mccabe==0.6.1=py37_1
  - defaults/linux-64::charls==2.2.0=h2531618_0
  - defaults/noarch::snowballstemmer==2.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::itsdangerous==2.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pandocfilters==1.4.3=py37h06a4308_1
  - defaults/linux-64::patchelf==0.13=h295c915_0
  - defaults/noarch::sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::intervaltree==3.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::charset-normalizer==2.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::conda-pack==0.6.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::wrapt==1.12.1=py37h7b6447c_1
  - defaults/linux-64::lazy-object-proxy==1.6.0=py37h27cfd23_0
  - defaults/linux-64::numpy-base==1.20.3=py37h74d4b33_0
  - defaults/noarch::openpyxl==3.0.9=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::importlib_metadata==4.8.2=hd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::anaconda-client==1.9.0=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::parso==0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::widgetsnbextension==3.5.1=py37_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libffi==3.3=he6710b0_2
  - defaults/linux-64::lcms2==2.12=h3be6417_0
  - defaults/linux-64::scipy==1.7.3=py37hc147768_0
  - defaults/linux-64::simplegeneric==0.8.1=py37_2
  - defaults/linux-64::libgfortran-ng==7.5.0=ha8ba4b0_17
  - defaults/noarch::pyparsing==3.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::fontconfig==2.13.1=h6c09931_0
  - defaults/noarch::rope==0.21.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::wheel==0.37.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::fastcache==1.1.0=py37h7b6447c_0
  - defaults/noarch::pickleshare==0.7.5=pyhd3eb1b0_1003
  - defaults/linux-64::_anaconda_depends==2021.11=py37_0
  - defaults/linux-64::olefile==0.46=py37_0
  - defaults/noarch::dataclasses==0.8=pyh6d0b6a4_7
  - defaults/linux-64::boto==2.49.0=py37_0
  - defaults/linux-64::brotlipy==0.7.0=py37h27cfd23_1003
  - defaults/linux-64::pytest==6.2.5=py37h06a4308_2
  - defaults/linux-64::inflection==0.5.1=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::appdirs==1.4.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pylint==2.9.6=py37h06a4308_1
  - defaults/linux-64::lerc==3.0=h295c915_0
  - defaults/linux-64::watchdog==2.1.6=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/linux-64::spyder-kernels==2.1.3=py37h06a4308_0
  - defaults/noarch::xlsxwriter==3.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::path==16.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
```

It seems it has something to do with cuda:

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining cudatoolkit:  25%|████████████████████▎                                                             | 132/533 [00:00<00:00, 4431.84it/ ^failed
```

My nvidia driver is 418.87.01 and cuda driver is 10.0, I want to also install PyTorch 1.7, so I did:

```
conda create -n km python=3.7 anaconda
    conda activate km
    conda install pytorch==1.7.1 torchvision==0.8.2 torchaudio==0.7.2 cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```

Then I did:

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
```

Now the error occurred. My goal is to install both PyTorch 1.7 and TF-gpu 1.15, so I have to use conda to install cudatoolkit=10.1. PyTroch requires at least cuda10.1, right?

How to fix the issue?

Comment: Is `anaconda` really needed for this env? Can you try to specify both pytorch and tensorflow during env creation? `conda create -n km python=3.7 pytorch==1.7.1 torchvision==0.8.2 torchaudio==0.7.2 cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0`

Answer (score 0):

Try and run this command, it worked for me:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

You can find more about the installlation on the official website [here](https://pytorch.org/)